# OpenSSL DER ECDSA encoding error

Tags: c++, openssl, ecdsa, der

I am trying to encode ECDSA Curve448 key into a small and portable byte array. I am trying to use DER to accomplish this, as the low-level APIs do not work with Curve448. However, when I use the following code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> vecs;
uint8_t* buf = nullptr;

EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_ED448, NULL);
EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(pctx);
EVP_PKEY* pkey;
EVP_PKEY_keygen(pctx, &pkey);
EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(pctx);

size_t n = i2d_PublicKey(pkey, &buf);

ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

vecs.emplace_back(buf, buf + n);
```

`n` is set to -1, and so `vecs.emplace_back` fails. ERR_print_errors_fp prints:

```
140691149055104:error:0D0A40A7:asn1 encoding routines:i2d_PublicKey:unsupported public key type:../crypto/asn1/i2d_pu.c:35
```

How do I solve this problem, or is there a better way I should go about this?

I am using openssl v1.1.1 from debian experimental.

Comment: Note that `i2d_PrivateKey()` returns an int (which is signed) not a size_t (which is unsigned) as you have in your code. When you say "n is set to -1", because you are storing it in a size_t, it is probably actually set to a very large positive number - this could cause you later problems if you test for "n < 0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write out a private key or a public key? I ask because your code above has `size_t n = i2d_PrivateKey(pkey, &buf);`, i.e. attempting to encode a private key, but the error message says `i2d_PublicKey:unsupported public key type`.

Anyway `i2d_PublicKey` is for writing out public keys in old-style "traditional" format. Since ED448 is a new algorithm, there is no such format defined for it. Instead you must use SubjectPublicKeyInfo format. The OpenSSL function for that is the (confusingly similar) `i2d_PUBKEY()`. The man page is here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/i2d_PUBKEY.html

Comment: Sorry, I am encoding both a private and a public key in my program, and the above was a slightly simplified example, in which I must have accidently copied the wrong line. I have updated the question.